# Problem adding image to UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm making an app with a piano and each key will be it's own subclass.

I tried making the keys a subclass of UIButton, but after having some problems getting the methods to be called, I checked online and found out that others were also having problems subclassing UIButtons.

So then I tried subclassing a UIView. The problem was that I tried adding an image to it, but it showed up as a black box.

Here is the code from the CustomView

```
@implementation Keys

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whitekey.gif"]];                                

}
return self;
```

(I've confirmed that the problem isn't whitekey.gif)

Here is the code from the viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


Keys *whiteKey = [[Keys alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:whiteKey];

}
```

Is it better if I subclass UIImageView?

Comment: Are you sure you'd have to subclass `UIButton`?

Comment: It's probably not going to fix your problem, but may I suggest you convert your `.gif` to a `.png` image instead?  `PNG` images are more optimized for the iOS platform (and Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using UIImageView.

> An image view object provides a view-based container for displaying
>   either a single image or for animating a series of images.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Maybe a UIView as a container, with a UIImageView with the piano key image, with additional UIViews on top of that, depending on what you need to do?

Comment: The image shows up w/ a UIImageView, but I can't override the touches began method like I could with a UIView

Comment: @Mahir E -- take a look at the accepted answer for the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855095/how-can-i-detect-the-touch-event-of-an-uiimageview

Comment: Yeah, i've added 
 [self.userInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
 [self.canBecomeFirstResponder:YES];